# Jquery - Get data attr value from button and compare within div to check exist

Tags: jquery

Here created the function to get offer code and upgrade bed code from the parent of Button click event. Compare within a div to check whether same offer code and upgrade code exists in any of "offer-container" in data-offer-code and data-selected-bed-code.

Not sure below code is the correct way to get the expected result.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div id="item1" class="content">
        <div class="left-container"><h1>Title 1</h1></div>
        <div class="right-container">
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code001" data-selected-bed-code="AA" data-upgrade-bed-code="BB">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow()">Book Now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code002" data-selected-bed-code="EEE" data-upgrade-bed-code="FFF">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow()">Book Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item2" class="content">
        <div class="left-container"><h1>Title 2</h1></div>
        <div class="right-container">
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code001" data-selected-bed-code="BB" data-upgrade-bed-code="CC">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow()">Book Now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code002" data-selected-bed-code="FFF" data-upgrade-bed-code="GGG">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow()">Book Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function bookNow(){
    var getOfferCode = $(this).parent().attr('data-offer-code');
    var getSelectedbedCode = $(this).parent().attr('data-selected-bed-code');
    var getUpgradeBedCode = $(this).parent().attr('data-upgrade-bed-code');

    //Get getOfferCode & getUpgradeBedCode from book now click event.
    //Check if same offer code & upgrade code exists in any of "offer-container" containers - data-offer-code & data-selected-bed-code
    $('.offer-container').each(function() {
        if((getOfferCode && getUpgradeBedCode).length){
            var getSelectedBedCode = getUpgradeBedCode;
            var getTitle = $(this).parent().find('.leftcontainer h1').html();
            console.log("Selected bed code: " +getSelectedBedCode);
            console.log("getOfferCode: " +getOfferCode);
            console.log("getTitle: " +getTitle);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `$(this)` inside the function sometimes not refer to the wanted element.. so you need to pass argument to your function `bookNow(el)` and use `el` instead of `this`
- Then In html `onClick` pass `this` to the function like `onClick="bookNow(this)"`

You can start from here ..

```js
function bookNow(el){
    var getOfferCode = $(el).parent().attr('data-offer-code');
    var getSelectedbedCode = $(el).parent().attr('data-selected-bed-code');
    var getUpgradeBedCode = $(el).parent().attr('data-upgrade-bed-code');

    $('.offer-container').each(function() {
        if($('[data-selected-bed-code="'+getSelectedbedCode+'"]').length && $('[data-selected-bed-code="'+getSelectedbedCode+'"]').length){
            var getSelectedBedCode = getUpgradeBedCode;
            var getTitle = $(el).closest('.content').find('h1').html();
            console.log("Selected bed code: " +getSelectedBedCode);
            console.log("getOfferCode: " +getOfferCode);
            console.log("getTitle: " +getTitle);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
    <div id="item1" class="content">
        <div class="left-container"><h1>Title 1</h1></div>
        <div class="right-container">
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code001" data-selected-bed-code="AA" data-upgrade-bed-code="BB">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow(this)">Book Now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code002" data-selected-bed-code="EEE" data-upgrade-bed-code="FFF">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow(this)">Book Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item2" class="content">
        <div class="left-container"><h1>Title 2</h1></div>
        <div class="right-container">
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code001" data-selected-bed-code="BB" data-upgrade-bed-code="CC">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow(this)">Book Now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code002" data-selected-bed-code="FFF" data-upgrade-bed-code="GGG">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow(this)">Book Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:** `$('[data-selected-bed-code="'+getSelectedbedCode+'"]').length` will return number above 0 if there is an element with the `getSelectedCode` exists .. you can use `== 1` to make check if just one element exists .. I don't know what you're trying to do with this `if(` but you can use the above code for checking.

> **Note** Don't forget to include jquery library if you didn't

Update:

```js
function bookNow(el){
    var getOfferCode = $(el).parent().attr('data-offer-code');
    var getSelectedbedCode = $(el).parent().attr('data-selected-bed-code');
    var getUpgradeBedCode = $(el).parent().attr('data-upgrade-bed-code');

    
   if($('*[data-offer-code="'+getOfferCode+'"][data-selected-bed-code="'+getSelectedbedCode+'"]').length > 1){
    $('*[data-offer-code="'+getOfferCode+'"][data-selected-bed-code="'+getSelectedbedCode+'"]').not($(el).closest('.offer-container')).each(function() {
        var getTitle = $(this).closest('.content').find('h1').html();
        console.log("getTitle: " +getTitle);
      });
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
    <div id="item1" class="content">
        <div class="left-container"><h1>Title 1</h1></div>
        <div class="right-container">
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code001" data-selected-bed-code="BB" data-upgrade-bed-code="BB">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow(this)">Book Now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code002" data-selected-bed-code="EEE" data-upgrade-bed-code="FFF">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow(this)">Book Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item2" class="content">
        <div class="left-container"><h1>Title 2</h1></div>
        <div class="right-container">
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code001" data-selected-bed-code="BB" data-upgrade-bed-code="CC">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow(this)">Book Now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="offer-container" data-offer-code="Code002" data-selected-bed-code="FFF" data-upgrade-bed-code="GGG">
                <h2>Offer Title</h2>
                <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="bookNow(this)">Book Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TDG see the updated answer .. But in your code `data-selected-bed-code="AA"` in 3rd one `data-selected-bed-code="BB"` so I changed it to `BB` in the first one

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed your logic based on your script. its updated above on your comment. But, i need only Title 2 on clicking on first "book now". But here it generates 2-title1 and 2 - titl2.